# Create a list with specific values with Autofixture C#

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture

The Model has properties `Id`, `Code` etc.

I want to create 4 data with specific different codes.

```
 var data = _fixture.Build<MyModel>()
                .With(f => f.Code, "A")
                .CreateMany(4);
```

This results in all 4 data with Code "A". I want the 4 data to have codes **"A", "B", "C", "D"**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you expect the sequence to continue (e.g. "D", "E", "F") or do you want just 4 models with these exact codes?

Comment: No, I want only 4 items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only need 4 items you can define your collection of codes and use it to generate the 4 models using LINQ.

```cs
public static object[][] Codes =
{
    new object[] { new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" } }
};

[Theory]
[MemberAutoData(nameof(Codes))]
public void Foo(string[] codes, Fixture fixture)
{
    var builder = fixture.Build<MyModel>(); // Do any other customizations here
    var models = codes.Select(x => builder.With(x => x.Code, x).Create());

    var acutal = models.Select(x => x.Code).ToArray();

    Assert.Equal(codes, acutal);
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it out and let you know

Answer (score 16):

There is an easier way to do this

```
string[] alphabets = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var queue = new Queue<string>(alphabets);

var data = _fixture.Build<MyModel>()
               .With(f => f.Code, () => queue.Dequeue())
               .CreateMany(alphabets.Length);
```

Output

```
[
  {Code: "A"},
  {Code: "B"},
  {Code: "C"},
  {Code: "D"}
]
```

In case if you want the result in reverse order use `Stack` instead of `Queue` and `Pop` instead of `Dequeue`

Comment: This is very elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This seems ripe for an extension method:

```
public static IPostprocessComposer<T> WithValues<T, TProperty>(this IPostprocessComposer<T> composer,
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyPicker,
        params TProperty[] values)
{
    var queue = new Queue<TProperty>(values);

    return composer.With(propertyPicker, () => queue.Dequeue());
}

// Usage:
var data = _fixture.Build<MyModel>()
           .WithValues(f => f.Code, "A", "B", "C", "D")
           .CreateMany(4);
```